# Can't use ng-click into a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, popover

i'am using a popOver that show a list of bottons, those buttons have a simple ng-click that is not working. can someone help me?
here a simple example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YfC6RxVMO3jmGguHXgXu?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You're cloning the HTML and rendering it outside of Angular, so it's not going to have any of the bindings you'd expect.  Instead of using Twitter's Bootstrap directly in your Angular application, I would recommend using Angular's UI Bootstrap instead.  It has its own popOver that was written to work with Angular:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#popover

Comment: ok, then how i can use html on popover attribute like i did on content attribute from twitter boostrap?

Comment: It seems you can currently with latest.  There's a patch you could incorporate that adds this functionality: Discussion: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/220 Pull Request: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/369 Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mmq5dPi6MIYeEMoCrYSB?p=preview